# VS Code 1.86 Less syntax highlighting not correct

Tags: visual-studio-code, less

Syntax highlighting in VS Code (v1.86.1) for Less files is incorrect for certain properties and values. Here are some of the properties there are issues with, though most properties/values are correctly highlighted. Highlighting seems to be correct with these same properties in SASS and CSS.

[image: incorrect syntax highlighting]

I have tried deleting everything in my settings.json related to Less, I tried installing the extension [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) and set it to be the default formatter for all files, and I have restarted the application after changing settings, after disabling various extensions, etc; but nothing seems to change the highlighting.

Comment: I see the same happening. Using VS Code 1.86.2. Missing highlighting for `gap` for example.

Answer (score 2):

I highly suspect this being due to the Less grammar update that happened in the VS Code update that just happened (1.86). See [the release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86#_new-less-grammar):

> The previous Less grammar has been archived and VS Code now uses the grammar from [Better-Less](https://github.com/radium-v/Better-Less) for Less syntax highlighting.

The relevant VS Code issue ticket tracking this is [Consider adopting a new Less grammar #171239](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171239)

If you find a bug, you should first check if an issue ticket has been raised in [the better-less repo's issue tracker](https://github.com/radium-v/Better-Less/issues), and if not, raise one there. You could also instead/additionally raise the issue ticket in VS Code's issue tracker, but you may as well just report upstream.

Comment: Thanks @starball, I've opened an issue with better-less: https://github.com/radium-v/Better-Less/issues/30